# Bad records in the data and how to load them into hive after writing them to separate files

Tags: hadoop, hive, pyspark

How to process the data while loading into hive tables?

I want to handle data loading of records which has:

1.extra comma at the end of file
2.Incorrect data in row

Example:

```
id,name,city,date  
1,Robert,Boston,10/11/2018  
2,John,Phoenix,11/12/2018  
3,Peter,Atlanta,1/1/2019,  
4,Tom,Portland,Willsonvile,2/2/2019
```

I want to reject bad records and load remaining into hive tables, in this example I would like to load rows 3 and 4 and just only load rows 1 and 2

Kindly let me know how do we handle bad data in real time environment?
Any other examples are greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you load data into hive table?

Comment: @Jainik Using Load command in Hive

Comment: Do you have any ETL job before that, which product this file. Best bet is to make change there. Data cleaning is the part of ETL job.